# Column not found: 1054 issue in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I got this error:

```
Column not found: 1054
```

For the following code:

```
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
$status="active";
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
// run query to select records
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM job INNER JOIN employer ON job.eid= employer.eid  WHERE employer.username=$username AND job.status=active ");
$stmt->execute();
```

I have two tables, `jobs` and `employer`. I am joining these two tables and getting results based on `username` and `status`

Comment: `$username` is a string. Missing the `'`s . `employer.username='$username'` and `job.status='active'`.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your variable $username within quotes.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM job INNER JOIN employer ON job.eid= employer.eid  WHERE employer.username = '".$username."' AND job.status= 'active'");
```

Hope this helps.